# how to obtain google map link using latitude and longitude

Tags: android, location

i have latitude and longitude but cant obtain link of google map,
how obtain google map link which contain my latitude and longitude , and after that this link send as SMS to other ....

plzzz help meee...

Comment: please give some more information and what you have done?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a URI like this

http://maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude

just put your obtained longitude and latitude to the URI.

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation you could ever want on google maps for static images is right here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Essentially: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[LATITUDE_HERE],[LONGITUDE_HERE]&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false

If you are looking for basic SMS you can blast each carriers sms number with this link via email...
  10digitphonenumber@vtext.com 
...etc
see complete list here: http://www.emailtextmessages.com